# Net::MQTT::Simple->new() hangs?

Tags: perl, mqtt

I'm attempting to use the [Net::MQTT::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::MQTT::Simple) package from cpan. The following is a modified version of the 'Object oriented' example on the same cpan page:

```
use Net::MQTT::Simple;

my $mqtt = Net::MQTT::Simple->new("test.mosquitto.org");

#This doesn't actually execute

print "After new";

$mqtt->run(
    "test" => sub {
        my ($topic, $message) = @_;
        die "The building's on fire" if $message > 150;
    },
    "#" => sub {
        my ($topic, $message) = @_;
        print "[$topic] $message\n";
    },
);
```

My script never seems to connect or at least the `print` line never gets executed. No error is reported and the program just hangs. The sever name is correct as I can connect via the mosquitto_sub client.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas/pointers on why this would be hanging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually does execute. You are not seeing the output of it because of buffering.

Either add a newline to `print`:

```
print "After new\n";
```

Or enable autoflush:

```
$| = 1;
print "After new";
```

(If you look at the code of `Net::MQTT::Simple` you'll see that there are no blocking operations in the constructor at all. It's waiting for the messages in `$mqtt->run`, I guess there are no messages matching the topics you are subscribing to, so it appears to be "stuck")